# How to catch an exception from another class?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5.3

I have a custom class:

```
class ActivationService extends SmsException {

    public function __construct()
    {
          $this->sms = new SmsSender();
    }

    public function method(){
        throw new SmsException(); // My custom exception
    }


    public function send(){
        $this->sms->sendSms($this->phone); // Here's where the error appeared
    }
}
```

So, when I call `$this->sms->sendSms` I get an error from  class `sms`.

I'm catching the custom exception like as:

```
try {    
    $activationService = new ActivationService();
    $activationService->send($request->phone);    
}
catch (SmsException $e) {    
    echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

But when I get the error inside the library (`class SmsSender`) in method: `send()` I can not catch it and I get the error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: It's probably not throwing an SmsException. Add another catch block for `\Exception` and see if that catches something.

Comment: Yes, `\Exception` works, but why my exception does not work if there is: `use Exception;

class SmsException extends Exception
{
    // TODO
}`

Comment: Do you need `\SmsException`? I know that namespaces can bugger this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possibly a namespace thing.

If `SmsException` is defined within a namespace, for example:

```
<?php namespace App\Exceptions;

class SmsException extends \Exception {
    //
}
```

and the code that is trying to catch the exception is defined within another namespace, or none at all, for example:

```
<?php App\Libs;

class MyLib {

    public function foo() {
        try {

            $activationService = new ActivationService();
            $activationService->send($request->phone);

        } catch (SmsException $e) {

            echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

then it will actaully be trying to catch `App\Libs\SmsException`, which isn't defined so the `catch` fails.

If this is the case try replacing `catch (SmsException $e)` with `catch (\App\Exceptions\SmsException $e)` (obviously use the correct namespaces), or put a `use` statement at the top of the file.

```
<?php App\Libs;

use App\Exceptions\SmsException;

class MyLib {

    // Code here...
```